# JQuery Get values from inputs in a while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Trying to get all values from within my while loop to use in jquery.

Here is my loop:

```
<%
      while (rs.next()) {
%>
        <%=StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("program"), "")%><br />
        <input type="hidden" id="program" name="program" value="<%=StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("program"), "")%>" />
<%
      }
%>
```

The values that should be returned are Art, Accounting.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var progs = $('#program').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    alert(progs);  // alerts Art
    alert(progs.length);  // alerts 1
```

So any ideas as to why this is only returning the first one?  Thanks in advance

Comment: *why this is only returning the first one?* bacause id must be unique use class instead .. `class="program"` and `$('.program')`

Comment: Ugh, that's embarassing.  Been a while since I have done this stuff and forgot the most obvious thing.  Thank you! If you create an answer i wlll accept

Comment: answer posted .. Have a great Day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*why this is only returning the first one?* because id must be unique use class instead ..

```
<%
      while (rs.next()) {
%>
        <%=StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("program"), "")%><br />
        <input type="hidden" class="program" name="program" value="<%=StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("program"), "")%>" />
<%
      }
%>
```

And

```
var progs = $('.program').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    alert(progs); 
    alert(progs.length);
```

> **Note**: If you don't have control to change the `id` to `class` you can use `$('[id^=program]')` selector instead of `$('#program')`